# Is there any way in Linux to show what's going on about the freezing code on the R session?

Tags: r

I am running a set of selected code on R. Like

```
source("/tmp/r-plugin-honli/Rsource-2704-quantmod.R")
```

There is no output. Only the prompt '>' flickered there.

I use 'killall' to kill the R session. But I don't know where is wrong on the code.  Because R did not give any output. How could I know what's going on about the code.

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to add `print()` statements at various places in your code.  The problem will be between the last one that prints and the next one that doesn't.

Comment: "How could I know what's going on about the code.": the best way to get this knowledge is to read the source code. Use the Source!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try two things:

Run the code interactively.  As in, open the Rsource-2704 file and run its lines one by one.

If that doesn't replicate the problem or is not possible, you can take Joshua Ulrich's suggestion or use:

```
R CMD BATCH --vanilla Rsource-2704-quantmod.R out.log
```

Which will run the code in a batch mode and output the usual console lines to a file called out.log (you can name it whatever you like).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `print` statements, you could also take a look at the `browser()` command. This drops you into an interactive session at the point where the command is put. This works particularly well when trying to figure out what is happening inside a function, although I don't know if your script contains them.